# String Cleaning in R down to just letters

Tags: string, r

so I'm trying to clean strings in R, and I want to be able to clean every string of all of the non-letter elements. I know I can just use gsub to do them individually, but I want to be able to take out all of them (excluding spaces), or if I get it down to just individual character strings with spaces removed, stripping those as well.

For example, if i have an email address as a string vector, "abc123@gmail.com", or a string vector of the form ("abc", "123", "abc123"), stripping them should yield "abcgmailcom" and ("abc", "", "abc") respectively. I'm only going to be working with vectors of multiple strings.

Comment: Please give an example of your strings, and how they are structured (in a list, column in dataframe etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
char <- c("dc2 54üx*","%67{~\\hjkh")
#[1] "dc2 54üx*"   "%67{~\\hjkh"
gsub("[^[:alpha:] ]","",char)
#[1] "dc üx" "hjkh"
```

Comment: Is there a way to leave alphanumerics, instead of just letters?

Comment: Yes, it's given in `?regex`.

Comment: +1 for not yielding and making the OP do *some* investigative work! I was going to cover `lapply`/`sapply` usage for when input data is in a list or `data.frame` too, but it feels like too much repetition.